# Differences between files and templates in ansible role dir

Tags: ansible

Ansible: 2.9

Hi!

What is the difference between this two dirs: "files" vs "templates" in ansible role tree?

I know how to work with "templates" dir but how I can work with "files" dir?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what a template is, a file is basically a template that doesn't need to be processed.

For instance, if your role needs a task to copy a file, you can use `copy` module:

```
- name: Copy a file
  copy:
    src: my_file.txt
    dest: /etc/wherever
```

In an Ansible role, `src` is relative to role's `files` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**How I can work with 'files' dir?**"*

A: Read the whole section [*The magic of ‘local’ paths*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths). Quoting only a part of it:

> ... "*Using this magic, relative paths get attempted first with a ‘files|templates|vars’ appended (if not already present), depending on the action being taken, ‘files’ is the default. (in other words, include_vars will use vars/). The paths will be searched from most specific to most general (in other words, role before play). dependent roles WILL be traversed (in other words, the task is in role2, role2 is a dependency of role1, role2 will be looked at first, then role1, then play)*" ...